# como puedo manipular la concatenación en c#

Tags: c#

necesito ayuda quiero realizar un pseudo código usando la concatenación es porque estoy aprendiendo a programar pero el profesor no me explica lo quiero hacer es que la variante int que es numero aumente mientras que la variante sntring que es resp solo se escriba una vez este es el codigo

```
using System;

namespace sumas2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("estos son los numeros primos del 1 al 5: ");
            string resp = "las variables son\ ";
            int num1 = 5;
            int numero = 1, divisible = 0;
            while (numero <= num1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
                {
                    if (numero % i == 0)
                    {
                        divisible++;
                    }
                    if (divisible > 2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (divisible == 2)
                { 
                    Console.Write(resp);
                    
                        Console.Write(numero);
                    }
                    divisible = 0;
                    numero++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ya he intentando con varias salidas de escape y no funciona como quiero

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es guardar cada número que cumpla la condición que quieres dentro de un `List` y al final cuando termine el ciclo `while`, simplemente lo imprimes mediante `Console.WriteLine()`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! muestra como queres que salga.. pero que pasa si simplemente imprimis resp antes de calcular los valores?

Answer (score 0):

Esta puede ser una forma de concatenar. Notaras que realice una variable para el resultado, y lo muestro todo fuera del ciclo para que no muestre todo el tiempo el resultado, sino que cuando haya terminado.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("estos son los numeros primos del 1 al 5: ");
        string resp = "las variables son: ";
        int num1 = 5;
        int numero = 1, divisible = 0;
        string concatenados = string.Empty;

        while (numero <= num1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
            {
                if (numero % i == 0)
                {
                    divisible++;
                }
                if (divisible > 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (divisible == 2)
            {
                concatenados +=  numero +" - ";
                //Console.Write(resp);

                //Console.Write(numero);
            }
            divisible = 0;
            numero++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resp + concatenados);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Resultado:

```
estos son los numeros primos del 1 al 5:
las variables son2 - 3 - 5 -
```

Comment: grax asi solo es copy y page

Comment: @lolxd132 si te sirvio marcala como aceptada

Comment: no se como hacerlo

Comment: @lolxd132 aca en la misma respuesta hay para votarla y aceptarla